# Key events on radio and checkboxes in Chrome not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a page which contains input fields of type radio and checkbox. I want to be able to trigger an event when the user presses a key whilst one of these input fields are focused.

My code is:

```
<li class="duplicatable">
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="v" />    
</li>
```

And in document load I apply the event handling:

```
$('.duplicatable').keypress(function(event) {
    console.log('pressed: ' + event);
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.duplicatable', function(event) {
    console.log('pressed: ' + event);
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$('.duplicatable > li') etc...
```

I have tested the click event which does work in Chrome and Firefox, but when this is a key event, Firework works, but Chrome does nothing.

Is Chrome not handling key events at all on radio and check boxes (or, rather li elements)?

Comment: Are you sure the input is focused? Note that clicking a radio button will select it, but won't actually focus it. (For example, if you go here http://jsfiddle.net/xymostech/v3naW/ and press tab, then it will actually focus, and you can get the events)

Comment: I don't think it's focused. I tried applying a label and the key press doesn't work for that either. http://jsfiddle.net/UGq6j/1/

This example also proves how Firefox does work for this but Chrome does not.

Comment: There is no `keypress` event for radio buttons, and they cannot capture user keystrokes, therefore this is implausible. @Xymostech and while that is correct, it's a futile point. refer to my aforementioned statement.

Comment: Well I got it working by attaching a click event to them which calls focus on the event's target. So your note did help :-)

Comment: Xymostech, if you want to put that as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bind the event directly on the input:

```
$('.duplicate input:checked').click(/*...*/)
```

Comment: Click is fine, but I need the event to trigger when the user presses a key after they have already selected the radio button.

Comment: Have you tried the pseudo class 'checked':     'input[name=radioName]:checked'