# keypress event does not triggered after choosing a choice from radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, keypress

Using `backbone js` i want to execute a function while hitting on the ENTER Key.

I have a form :

1. When i enter a vallue in an input and hit enter, the function is triggered and works fine.
2. When i choose a button radio and hitting enter my function isn't called. Not OK

I am using this code in my view:

```
View.FormCustomer = CommonViews.FormCustomer.extend({
    title : "Ajouter une fiche",            
},

events: {  
     "keypress": "getKeyCode"
},

getKeyCode: function(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode == "13"){
        this.save(e);
    }               
},
```

Does any one have any suggestions?

Comment: You said checkbox in title... radio button in description... what is it.. can you create a [mcve]..?

Comment: See comments on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18564815/3585500) about the radio button being focused (or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to listen to that keypress event at the document and not in your events object.

```
...
  initialize: function(){
  var _this = this;

    $(document).on('keypress.namespace', function(){
      _this.someMethod();
    }); 
    },
  ...
    //you'll have to remove that event when you ditch your view, assuming you have already override your remove method...
    remove: function(){
      $(document).off('.namespace');
    }
```